# Is it possible to get the state of an Azure Monitor alert programmatically?

Tags: azure

I have the following code:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(configuration.AzureClientId, configuration.AzureClientSecret, configuration.AzureTenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithSubscription(configuration.AzureSubscriptionId);
var alert = azure.AlertRules.MetricAlerts.GetById("stuff");
var isFiring = alert.???
```

and I want to get whether the alert is firing or not, using the fluent api. Is there any way of doing this programmatically, preferably via the fluent api, but would also consider other ways though would prefer not to execute powershell via my C# code.

Answer (score 0):

[Alert state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview#manage-alerts) is different and independent of the monitor condition. Alert state is set by the user. Monitor condition is set by the system. **When an alert fires, the alert's monitor condition is set to fired.**  When the underlying condition that caused the alert to fire clears, the monitor condition is set to resolved.

Here is [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getbyid) that you could get the `alertState`.